# Class is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization

Tags: corda

In Corda, I have defined the following flow:

```
object Flow {
    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    class Initiator(val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
        override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            val otherPartyFlow = initiateFlow(otherParty)
            otherPartyFlow.send(MyClass())
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
    class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            val unregisteredClassInstance = otherPartyFlow.receive<MyClass>()
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try and run the flow, I get the following error:

> Class com.example.flow.MyClass is not annotated or on the whitelist,
>   so cannot be used in serialization

How can I annotate or whitelist the class to allow it to be sent within the flow? Why do I need to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, for security purposes, only classes present on the [default serialization whitelist](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V2/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/serialization/DefaultWhitelist.kt) can be sent within flows or over RPC.

There are two ways to add a specific class to the serialization whitelist:

**1. Annotating the class as @CordaSerializable:**

```
@CordaSerializable
class MyClass
```

**2. Creating a serialization whitelist plugin:**

Define a serialisation plugin as follows:

```
class TemplateSerializationWhitelist : SerializationWhitelist {
    override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> = listOf(MyClass::class.java)
}
```

Then list the serialization whitelist plugin's fully-qualified class name (e.g. `com.example.TemplateSerializationWhitelist` in a file called `net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist` in the `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` folder of your CorDapp.

**Why are there two ways to add a class to the serialization whitelist?**

The first approach is easier, but is not possible when you're not able to add the annotation to the class you wish to send.

Comment: Does the build generate that file automatically by scanning the classes for implementations of SerializationWhitelist?